# Linux/Chromium: add startpage.com as default search engine

Tags: chromium, search-engines

I'm trying to add [StartPage.com](https://www.startpage.com/) as default search engine (so I can use it when opening a new tab, by just writing into the address bar as it is the case for searching with Google so far).
I've found those descriptions which all deviate from what I'm seeing in my Chromium on Linux (version 106.0.5249.91):

- [StartPage instructions](https://support.startpage.com/hc/en-us/articles/5319991439380-Set-Startpage-as-default-search-engine-in-Chromium)
- another [Startpage description](https://add.startpage.com/protection-success/)
- question [on this forum](https://superuser.com/questions/1262748/how-to-set-a-default-search-engine-in-chromium)

The Chromium description in section "Edit search engine" reads "URL with %s in place of query", but that doesn't work because StartPage does not use URL arguments for the search.
The "Keep it" / "Keep changes" as in the StratPage instructions never shows up after installing the Startpage chromium extension.

If I wanna search via Startpage, currently I have to either visit the website and then enter the search, or I can click the extension symbol and then click "search".

Is there any way to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StartPage does use URL arguments for the search, like this :

```
https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=%s
```

The official way is described in the article
[Search strings / adding Startpage to unsupported web browsers](https://support.startpage.com/hc/en-us/articles/4520913488148-Search-strings-adding-Startpage-to-unsupported-web-browsers)
is to use :

```
https://www.startpage.com/sp/search?query=%s
```

Comment: Hm...okay, embarrassing. However, in none of the instructions I found that piece of information. And using the search on startpage, it doesn't show the arguments in the URL (unlike other search engines). Thanks!

Comment: As a user of StartPage, I found this URL by using it, not via the documentation.

Comment: Okay, default http request is POST, where the search string is not part of the URL (which was the case for me so far). But GET requests are also possible -- and I now found [this description](https://support.startpage.com/hc/en-us/articles/4520913488148-Search-strings-adding-Startpage-to-unsupported-web-browsers)

Comment: I added your find to my answer,